# Retained Fragment: AsyncTask and Screen Rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, screen-rotation

I have a retained fragment in my app that download some data from a webservice and show result inside a listview. This is my implementation of oncreate and oncreate view

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //retain fragment for configuration change
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          // i'm here when fragment is created first time
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
          // call a private method for init my widgets
          setWidgets(view); 
          //call here asynctask for download data
    } else {
        // i'm here after a configuration change, just update views
        String myData = MyApp.getStoredData().toString();
        // update my widget with previous stored data
    }

}
```

MyApp is my class that extend Application, and keep data downloaded by asynctask. 
Now if i rotate device when AsyncTask is finished, everithing is ok, but if i rotate device while AsyncTask is not finished yet, i obtain a nullpointer exception when i call MyApp.getStoredData().toString() (i call toString on a null object).

How can i do to fix it?

Comment: In `MyApp.getStoredData().toString()` method you may do task asynchronously but  this method will return immediately .

Comment: MyApp.getStoredData().toString(); you should post code inside my app async task also, so one can tell you best solution for this.

Comment: @Khemraj the asynctask download and parse some data from a webservice, and store result in an object that should be returned by getStoredData()